# Jar with Sparks Framework only works right with console not with double click

Tags: java, jar, spark-java

the structure is

- program.jar
- www (folder)

www is a folder with changing files for Spark, so i use

```
externalStaticFileLocation("www");
```

when i run

```
java -jar program.jar
```

http://localhost:8080/index.html works

when i start the jar with a double click

the url return 404 not found.

Anyone who can help me?

Thank you

Comment: It looks that the *working directory* is different when you're executing from cmd line and when executing using double click. Did you try to output that to some log and see if there's a difference?

Comment: The working directory seems to bee the directory with the jar inside. On both

Comment: wehen i start jar with double click the path is my home directory under linux... thats realy strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Answer is this

```
    private static String getWWWDir() {
       String dir = new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "/www";
       File file = new File(dir);

       if(file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
           return file.getAbsolutePath();
       }
       else
       {
           String tmpDir = API.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile();
           file = new File(tmpDir);
           dir = file.getParent() + "/www";
           file = new File(dir);
           if(file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
               return file.getAbsolutePath();
           }
       }
       return null;
   }
```

I know its not beautiful but it works for me.

Thank your guys for helping

Answer (score 0):

I usually use absolute path with `externalStaticFileLocation`

**Edit**

I also have an application in which, for development purposes, I obtain the path in which the jar is being executed. For you, I think a nice solution would be:

Declare a string, in my application it was a constant

```
    public static final String STATIC_FILES_LOCATION_DEV;
```

Create a File instance and obtain the current directory, then concatenate the `www` directory

```
    File f = new File("");
    STATIC_FILES_LOCATION_DEV = f.getAbsolutePath()
            + "/../www";
```

Use it as your resource directory:

```
    externalStaticFileLocation(STATIC_FILES_LOCATION_DEV);
```

That's it.

Comment: but how did i know where the user have the jar file? And if is use the path where the jar runs, i cant debug the project anymore because in Project there is a target folder and with jar there is no target folder

Comment: When you export your jar, are all your web assets (html, css, js files) inside the jar? Please check it by opening your jar with winzip.

Comment: no there are no web assets in the jar. The www is an external folder in the same directory as the jar. Because the tool download html files into www and therefore i cant use them in the jar

Comment: I think you have two options then: put the web assets inside your classpath and start using `staticFileLocation` or standardize a path for the www folder at the machine that will run your website and reference it by absolute path in the `externalStaticFileLocation`.

Comment: I've eddited the answer, take a look!

Comment: your update doesnt work, but it make thing clearer. f.getAbsolutePath() is my home directory when i start jar with double click oO